# Move widget between frames (tkinter & python 3)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a video streaming application using tkinter (python 3.8.5) and want to move my stream widgets between different frames. My approach to moving the widget between frames is calling `pack_forget()` followed by `pack(in_=new_frame)`. However when I do this, the window is empty, other widgets that I didn't call `pack_forget()` on don't show up either. I checked `pack_info()` and it shows the location I would expect. Does anyone have an explanation/solution for this behavior? I'm fairly new to tkinter so if I'm making a newbie mistake or using the wrong tools please let me know.

This example reproduces the behavior I'm seeing:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

test = tkinter.Label(root,text="test")
test2 = tkinter.Label(root,text="test2")

frame1 = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
test2.pack(in_=frame1)
frame2 = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

test.pack(in_=frame1)

test.pack_forget()

test.pack(in_=frame2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I use `bg='red'` in `Frames` then I see `in_` resizes frames but it has problem to display text.

Comment: code works for me if I create `Labels` after `Frames`

Comment: yeah it does, interesting. I could potentially make that work although it will involve some otherwise unnecessary destruction and reinitialisation of widgets; that might cause memory leaks but i think i can manage that. Would you consider creating frames before widgets a common good practice?

Comment: I always create frames before widgets - and probably in most examples on Stackoverflow you see frames before widgets. I don't understand why to create them after widgets. Always `from top to bottom` - first window, next frames which go directly to window, and next widgets which go to frames.